# XML local-name replacement through XSLT

Tags: xslt-1.0

I want to convert following code

================

```
<spirit:parameter>
    <spirit:name>P3</spirit:name>
          <spirit:test_value>8</spirit:test_value>
        </spirit:parameter>
</spirit:parameters>
```

================

into

================

```
<spirit:parameter>
    <spirit:name>P3</spirit:name>
          <spirit:glue_value>8</spirit:glue_value>
        </spirit:parameter>
</spirit:parameters>
```

================

I want to do it through XSLT. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Your example input wasn't quite valid, so changed it slightly and added a namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<spirit:parameters xmlns:spirit="http://example.com/namespace/spirit">
    <spirit:parameter>
        <spirit:name>P3</spirit:name>
        <spirit:test_value>8</spirit:test_value>
    </spirit:parameter>
</spirit:parameters>
```

You essentially want to copy all nodes except 'spirit:test_value' which needs to be renamed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:spirit="http://example.com/namespace/spirit">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration='yes'/>

    <xsl:template match="spirit:parameters|spirit:parameter|spirit:name">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="spirit:test_value">
        <spirit:glue_value>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </spirit:glue_value>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The '`<xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>`' sections there are optional, you'd need those if you want to copy across any attributes from the source XML.